# Java 8 Stream add elements to list and sum

Tags: java, collections, java-8, sum, java-stream

I believe I can do next using one stream operation on listOfPricedObjects:

```
List<BigDecimal> myList = new ArrayList();
myList = listOfPricedObjects.stream().map(PricedObject::getPrice).collect(Collectors.toList());
BigDecimal sum = listOfPricedObjects.stream().map(PricedObject::getPrice).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
```

How I can fill myList with prices and calculate sum of prices using stream one time? 
Thanks

UPD: As the result I need myList filled with prices and sum variable with sum. But not with usding stream() twice for that.

Comment: Gathering stream elements in a list while also summing them into a variable requires side effects, which is discouraged for streams (as described in Oracle docs for Streams)

Comment: What happened to the clean code concept of a method doing only one thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `peek` and add to a new `list` while applying the reduction

```
List<BigDecimal> newList = new ArrayList<>();
BigDecimal sum = list.stream()
                     .map(PricedObject::getPrice)
                     .peek(newList::add)
                     .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Please look at Tunaki answer if you interested in using a `parallelStream` with a non concurrent collection which makes sense since sum is an embarrassingly parallel task.

Comment: Does newList have always the same order of prices as initial list had?

Answer (score 7):

What you want here is to collect your elements inside 2 collectors: the first one would collect into a list, and the second one would sum the price.

Since there are no such collectors in the Stream API itself, we can easily construct our own. Let's create a class `ResultHolder` that will hold the result of the Stream pipeline: this is the list of decimals and the sum.

```
class ResultHolder {
    List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<>();
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

Finally, we can use it with:

```
ResultHolder resultHolder = 
    listOfPricedObjects.stream()
            .map(PricedObject::getPrice)
            .collect(
                ResultHolder::new,
                (r, p) -> { r.list.add(p); r.sum = r.sum.add(p); },
                (r1, r2) -> { r1.list.addAll(r2.list); r1.sum = r1.sum.add(r2.sum); }
            );
System.out.println(resultHolder.list);
System.out.println(resultHolder.sum);
```

This will work in a parallel pipeline and will keep the initial order of the list, contrary to the other answers.

Comment: This is the only clean solution for `Stream` API.

Answer (score 4):

While it might be reasonable to assume use cases where an arbitrary stream like `listOfPricedObjects` can’t be recreated from the source and hence, only traversed once, you can safely assume that traversing the list produced via `Collectors.toList()` can be traversed efficiently:

```
List<BigDecimal> myList = listOfPricedObjects.stream()
    .map(PricedObject::getPrice).collect(Collectors.toList());
BigDecimal sum = myList.stream().reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

There is no code duplication here and any attempt to perform these two unrelated operations in one stream traversal will make the code more complicated without any benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shouldn't myList.stream() create a new stream that can be inefficient?

Comment: The list returned by `Collectors.toList()` can be traversed efficiently (currently it’s just an `ArrayList`) and streams created from it are just wrappers around that capability, i.e. the stream is iterating over the internal array of that list. There is no data structure in Java that could be traversed faster…

Answer (score 2):

You could do a identity mapping a add the passthrough value to the list

```
BigDecimal sum = listOfPricedObjects.stream()
                                    .map(o -> {
                                         myList.add(o); 
                                         return o;})
                                    .map(PricedObject::getPrice)
                                    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
```

But I'd go for Sleiman Jneidi's solution using peek(), its more elegant

Comment: I need myList filled with prices also. Your example just gets the sum.

Comment: forgot the "pass-through" mapping, does this help now?

Comment: Yes, thanks it works! looks like maps can be changed with each other for this example.