# Process certain stream elements last

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I have an interface which I must implement that expects a Stream response.  Some elements in my source are missing data, and I have to use other elements in the source to find it.  It is too large to hold all the elements in memory.  I can write a routine to find the missing data, but only if I process the elements missing the data last.

Here is a simplified example of my attempt to solve this.  In this case I am trying to save the 30 element for processing at the end after an additional routine of addOne.  But I am receiving a ConcurrentModificationException when the program attempts to read from the List Stream.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TestStreams {
    private static List<Integer> savedForLater = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<Integer> origStream = Stream.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50).filter(
                i -> saveThirtyForLater(i));
        Stream<Integer> savedForLaterStream = savedForLater.stream().map(
                i -> addOne(i));

        // Exception
        Stream.concat(origStream, savedForLaterStream).forEach(
            i -> System.out.println(i));

        // No Exception
        // origStream.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
        // savedForLaterStream.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
    }

    private static Integer addOne(Integer i) {
        return new Integer(i + 1);
    }

    private static boolean saveThirtyForLater(Integer i) {
        if (i == 30) {
            savedForLater.add(i);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This code produces the following result:

```
10
20
40
50
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at test.TestStreams.main(TestStreams.java:17)
```

I have tried using a threadsafe list, but it doesn't produce the desired result either.

Per JavaDoc Stream.concat Creates a **lazily** concatenated stream whose elements are all the elements of the first stream followed by all the elements of the second stream.

The concat on the streams should not invoke the List's stream until it pulls an object from it, at which point the list isn't changing.

If all else fails I could read the file twice, but I would really like to know why this doesn't work, and if anyone has an alternate idea about manipulating the stream to avoid a second pass.

Comment: Creating a custom collector that does both operations is one way to solve your problem. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37188002/829571

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're trying to do here. Could you focus on the actual problem?

Comment: @assylias How I could use a custom collector if my data is too large to store in memory?

Comment: @Tunaki I have to process a very large file into a Stream<Record>.  I can't create Record objects for some lines of the file until I have processed other lines of the file, so I would like to delay the processing of those specific lines until the end to mutate them with an additional routine based on the previously processed lines, eventually appending them to the end of the returned Stream.

Comment: Don’t use the constructor `new Integer(…)`. In case you don’t know about the method `Integer.valueOf(…)`, just use `return i+1;` and let the compiler do the work for you. Regarding the main question, don’t use Streams if you have such dependencies; it’s the wrong tool for your job.

Answer (score 2):

Streams are lazy. Unless you use terminal operation such as `forEach` or `collect`, intermediate operations (such as `filter` or `map`) will not be executed.

```
Stream<Integer> origStream = Stream.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50).filter(
        i -> saveThirtyForLater(i));
```

After executing above line of code, your `savedForLater` list remains unchanged. It will be modified only after you use terminal operation on this stream.

In your final expression `Stream.concat(origStream, savedForLaterStream).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));` you use terminal operation `forEach` on both streams `origStream` and `savedForLaterStream`. The former stream will modify `savedForLater` list while the latter actually iterates over it - this is the reason why you get `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Modifying a field in `filter` method is a very bad approach and it actually violates the contract of the `filter` method. From its javadoc:

> predicate - a non-interfering, stateless predicate to apply to each element to determine if it should be included

Your predicate `saveThirtyForLater` is not stateless as it modifies `savedForLater` list.

**Solution:**

Instead of using `concat`, you can process these streams separately, one after the other:

```
origStream.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
savedForLaterStream.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

These yields desired result:

```
10
20
40
50
31
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to return a single stream to another class for the actual processing.

I am not modifying the stream element in the filter, I am just adding it to a list of 'filtered out' objects.  Then later, I am modifying it as part of a map operation.

Where I agree that the program is dying is in the forEach terminal operation, however I don't believe it should be.  The forEach of the Stream.concat is for some reason initializing savedForLaterStream before origStream is fully consumed.  But according to the doc, Stream.concat should be lazy.

Comment: @Aaron I advise reading my answer again more carefully, because it seems that you didn't get the point - you have a stream which is both reading the list and modifying it. If you have to return a stream... You could collect the original stream to list assuming it is finite and not too big.

Comment: Actually, the streams `origStream` and `savedForLaterStream` are already consumed at the time `Stream.concat(origStream, savedForLaterStream)` is invoked. So the time span during which modifications to `savedForLater` are forbidden ranges from the invocation of `concat` to the completion of the terminal action. Though you won’t notice your mistake before the terminal action tries to process elements of `savedForLaterStream`…

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do the trick with `concat` as it breaks late-binding. It requests the sizes of both streams immediately when invoked, so you should know in advance how many elements will be saved for later. However it's possible to do this with `flatMap`, thanks to late-binding:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Integer> origStream = Stream.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50).filter(
            i -> saveThirtyForLater(i));
    Stream<Integer> savedForLaterStream = savedForLater.stream().map(
            i -> addOne(i));

    Stream.of(origStream, savedForLaterStream)
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .forEach(
        i -> System.out.println(i));
}
```

This code works nicely and prints `10 / 20 / 40 / 50 / 31`. Though it will work unpredictably if you parallelize it.

Note that my solution heavily relies on *current implementation* of Stream API in OpenJDK/OracleJDK. Stream API specification explicitly says that the predicate used in `filter` must be stateless and non-interfering. As these properties are violated here, the result, by specification, is unpredictable.

Comment: Keep in mind that `forEach` does not guaranty any ordering, thus, when using this trick together with `forEach` it’s not guaranteed to work. This applies to all terminal operations which can ignore encounter order.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: exactly.

Comment: @Holger, actually even with `forEachOrdered` spec does not guarantee that second stream reading will start only after full processing of the first stream. So my solution heavily relies on current implementation. You're always stepping on slippery ground when produce side-effects during stream traversal. (of course there's more clean solution involving my StreamEx library, but I'm too lazy to post it).

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: the function you have passed to `flatMap` should be evaluated *lazily*. Only the programmer knows that the stream already exists and the function is just an identity function. I’d say an implementer evaluating that function earlier than necessary in a sequential execution will be stepping on slippery ground either. Nevertheless, I would avoid any stream solution that obviously fails as soon as it is executed in parallel, even if I never plan to run it in parallel. To me “*Would this still work in parallel?*” is some kind of quality check.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help from others, but did want to post my ultimate solution.

I used a LinkedBlockingQueue and a custom Spliterator instead of an ArrayList.  Calling Stream.concat immediately generates the Spliterators of the argument streams (arguably unnecessarily).  The ArrayListSpliterator is not tolerant to modification of the list once it has been generated as pointed out by others.

The LinkedBlockingQueue by default has a [weakly consistent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly) spliterator, which **may** return items added to the underlying queue after the initialization of the spliterator.  In my tests, it consistently did, however, to avoid any chance of differing production behavior, I provided a custom spliterator which **will** return items added to the underlying queue after its initialization.  The QSpliterator code was copied from: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105308

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class TestStreams {
    private static LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> savedForLater = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<Integer> origStream = Stream.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50).filter(
                i -> saveThirtyForLater(i));
        Spliterator<Integer> qSpliterator = new QSpliterator<>(savedForLater);
        Stream<Integer> savedForLaterStream = StreamSupport.stream(
                qSpliterator, false).map(i -> addOne(i));

        Stream.concat(origStream, savedForLaterStream).forEach(
                i -> System.out.println(i));
    }

    private static Integer addOne(Integer i) {
        return new Integer(i + 1);
    }

    private static boolean saveThirtyForLater(Integer i) {
        if (i == 30) {
            savedForLater.add(i);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static final class QSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

        private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;

        public QSpliterator(BlockingQueue<T> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            try {
                action.accept(queue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new IllegalStateException("Take interrupted.", e);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
            try {
                final int size = queue.size();
                List<T> vals = new ArrayList<>(size + 1);
                vals.add(queue.take());
                queue.drainTo(vals);
                return vals.spliterator();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Thread interrupted during trySplit.", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long estimateSize() {
            return Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public int characteristics() {
            return Spliterator.CONCURRENT;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use foreign code unless you fully understand it. For someone who understands how it works, it’s obvious that this will create an *infinite* Stream which will never return if you use a terminal action that tries to process *all* elements.